# How can I access a user's email with my chatbot?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts

I'm making a Hangouts chatbot for my company, and one of the things we need to do is retrieve a user's email address. The API guide says that chatbot should be able to access this information without any additional permissions or API's, but I can't find out how to do it. I can get the user object from the event, but from that I can only get displayName.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can access an email with event.user.email
Doesn't say that anywhere in the documentation but whatever...

Comment: Event array gives you lots of other parameters as well. Do check them out via console.log